# jquery prevent mouseup if mousemove has previously been called

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouse

I have a `div` containing a number of `span` buttons displayed horizontally. There are too many buttons to fit on the screen so I want the user to be able to click and drag the whole row of buttons. However, I don't want the button's `mouseup` event to fire if the row has been dragged.

The `holder` only contains `button` elements. Here is the ASCII representation:

```
-------------------------------
| btn | btn | btn | btn | btn |
-------------------------------
```

Below is the code setup. Currently the `mouseup` handler on the button is being called before the handler on the holder (handlers being called in the bubbling phase), so calling `event.preventPropagation()` in the holder's `mouseup` handler doesn't help.

```
<div id="holder">
    <span class="button"></span>
</div>

$('#holder').mousedown( function () {
    $(document).mousemove( function () {
        // scroll content of #holder
    } ).mouseup( function () {
        // stop scrolling
        $(document).unbind('mouseup').unbind('mousemove');
    } );
} );

$('.button').mouseup( function () {
    $('document').mousemove( function () {
        // do some action here, but only if holder hasn't scrolled on mousedown
    } );
} );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a global variable to control the flow, something like this:

```
var scrolled = false;

$('#holder').mousedown( function () {
    $(document).mousemove( function () {
        scrolled = true;
        // scroll content of #holder

    } ).mouseup( function () {
        // stop scrolling
        $(document).unbind('mouseup').unbind('mousemove');
    } );
} );

$('.button').mouseup( function () {
    $('document').mousemove( function () {
        if (scrolled == false) {
            // do some action here, but only if holder hasn't scrolled on mousedown
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I thought there might be a more elegant solution :) I would of course have to set `scrolled = false` in the document mouseup handler...